# Practical applications of knot concordance

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, knot-theory, invariance, knot-invariants

Could someone mention some of the practical applications of knot concordance? I was not able to find any from [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C21&q=applications%20of%20knot%20concordance&btnG=). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect any? Most pure math does not have any (known) practical applications.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, I don't expect one only because I am not a domain expert. I would love to know if there is any.

Comment: So, your expectation is correct, there are no applications.

Comment: I'm not sure if in physics there are ever time-traveling knots, but if so that might be a source of "practical" applications.

Comment: @KyleMiller, is there a literature or reference for time-traveling knots?